# iOS app randomly puts itself into "Do Not Include" section, within Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, push-notification

We have an iPhone app that uses [Parse](http://parse.com) for Remote Notifications.

We register the user/device for remote notifications via the following:

```
    // Register for remote notifications the iOS8+ way or the older way
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // Register the iOS8 way

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
                                            UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                            UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                            UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                        categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    // Register the old way (pre iOS8)

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

This works fine. Immediately following this, we are seeing notifications being delivered to devices, as expected.

But, occasionally, we will notice that a device doesn't seem to be getting notifications anymore. After inspection, we see that the app puts itself into the "Do Not Include" section, within Notifications. We have not yet been able to determine a pattern of when or why this happens.

[image]

Have you seen this? Why would an app decide to deny notifications like this [unprompted by the user]?